# NavMeshAgent is not calculating a new path

Tags: unity, c#

I have the following code that gets run when a game object collides with a trigger. When the object is created, it is created within an initial trigger which fires the `SetNextWaypoint` code below and it works fine.

```
protected NavMeshPath path;
protected NavMeshAgent agent = null;

void Start () {
    path = new NavMeshPath();
    agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
}

public void SetNextWaypoint(Vector3 location){
    agent.ResetPath();
    path.ClearCorners();
    agent.CalculatePath(nextWayPoint, path);
    agent.SetPath(path);
}
```

Once the agent enters a new waypoint (it may not have reached its destination yet) `SetNextWaypoint` is called again and when it does the agent just stops where it is, and doesn't move anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! The issues was that my next waypoint was positioned too far above the NavMesh. But for some reason `path.status` was still returning `PathComplete`.

Moving the Waypoint closer to the navmesh allowed the object to go to the next Waypoint instead of just stopping.